# Android cursor adapter

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I would like to access one row of data at the time from the android sqlitedatabase. I've got working to load all the data, but can't get a single row working. Any suggestiong? Here is my code for the Load all part. Thanks.

```
public void LoadGrid()
{
    dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try
    {
        //Cursor c=dbHelper.getAllEmployees();
        View v=spinDept1.getSelectedView();
        TextView txt=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtDeptName);
        String Dept=String.valueOf(txt.getText());
        Cursor c=dbHelper.getEmpByDept(Dept);
        c.moveToFirst();

        c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));

        startManagingCursor(c);

        String [] from=new String []{DatabaseHelper.colName,DatabaseHelper.colAge,DatabaseHelper.colDeptName,DatabaseHelper.colKezd,DatabaseHelper.colVegz};
        int [] to=new int [] {R.id.colName,R.id.colAge,R.id.colDept,R.id.colKezd,R.id.colVegz};
        SimpleCursorAdapter sca=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.gridrow,c,from,to);
        grid.setAdapter(sca);



    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder b=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        b.setMessage(ex.toString());
        b.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use "LIMIT 1" at the end of your query.

Comment: sorry i'm new to sqlitdatabase, could you explain a bit more? :S thanks

Comment: Well show us the query you use to get the data from DB.

Comment: Sorry this one: Cursor getAllEmployees()
  {
   SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
   
   
   
   //Cursor cur= db.rawQuery("Select "+colID+" as _id , "+colName+", "+colAge+" from "+employeeTable, new String [] {});
   Cursor cur= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+viewEmps,null);
   return cur;
   
  }

Comment: and this:  public Cursor getEmpByDept(String Dept)
  {
   SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
   String [] columns=new String[]{"_id",colName,colAge,colDeptName,colKezd,colVegz,colComm};
   Cursor c=db.query(viewEmps, columns, colDeptName+"=?", new String[]{Dept}, null, null, null);
   return c;
  }

Answer (score 0):

I also came through this problem.Hope you have a column for serial number(sno)which starts from one.Initialize i to 1 in the activity. 
To populate one by one give query like
"SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE sno>'" + i + "' ORDER BY sno LIMIT 1"
Else
if you are using cursor,you can pass the LIMIT as a argument in string type like "1".